# On Nonparametric bootstrap predictive distributions

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, bootstrap

Consider a model $p(x|\boldsymbol{\theta})$ which is trained using $N$ i.i.d. observations $X=\left\{x_1, \ldots, x_N\right\}$. Bayesian predictive distribution is defined as
\begin{equation}
p(\bar{x} \mid X)=\int p(\bar{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid X) d \boldsymbol{\theta}
\end{equation}
which accounts for uncertainty about $\boldsymbol{\theta}$. [Fushiki (2005)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1116340296) proposed non-parametric bootstrap predictive distribution
\begin{equation}
    p_B(\bar{x} \mid X)=\int p(\bar{x} \mid \theta_{MLE}(\tilde{X})) \hat{p}(\tilde{X}) d \tilde{X}
\end{equation}
where $\theta_{MLE}(\tilde{X})$ is the MLE calculated from a non-parametric bootstrap sample $\tilde{X}$ independently obtained from the empirical distribution
\begin{equation}
\hat{p}(x)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \delta\left(x-x_{i}\right)
\end{equation}
He states that

> the nonparametric bootstrap predictive distribution coincides with the
> parametric bootstrap predictive distribution up to second order.

I was wondering:

1. What does "second order" refer to in the statement above.
2. Is this an approximation of Bayesian predictive distribution?
3. Does this model the posterior $p(\boldsymbol{\theta}|X)$ to account for the variability of parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta}$? How?